# Bad Value needs an array in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use $in inside $match condition of aggregate. I have SegmentList as literal array and Segment as a literal value. I am trying to match with $in condition as in query below.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{'$match': {
    'MaterialNumber': '867522'
}}, 
 {'$project':{
    'SegmentList': {'$literal':['A']},
           'Segment':{'$literal':'A'},
           'value':{'$literal':'B'},
       }
   },
       {'$match': {
    'Segment':{'$in':'$SegmentList'}
 }
 }

])
```

But I am getting an error.

```
assert: command failed: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "bad query: BadValue: $in needs an array",
"code" : 16810
} : aggregate failed
```

I am not not able to understand what is problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are intending to acheive here as all you are doing comparing if 'A' is in array with element 'A' which is always true.

`$match` in its regular form only takes a value not field reference.

No need to use `$literal` you can directly pass [].

You can use one of the following query based on mongo version.

3.4 & below:

```
{'$match': {'Segment':{'$in':['A']}}
```

3.6 ( not needed for your use case )

```
{'$match': {'$expr':{'$in':['$Segment', ['A']]}}}
```